# .NET MAUI Image wrong size

Tags: xamarin, maui

I'm having a problem when I show an image on .NET MAUI, the size of the image is always bigger than it actually is (blue part in the image below).

[image]

My code is as follows:

```xml
<Grid>
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <Image Source="https://cdn-5e5150f5f911c807c41ebdc8.closte.com/wp-content/uploads/IoT-development-kit-article-banner-scaled-900x400.jpg"
                    Aspect="AspectFit" BackgroundColor="Blue">
                <Image.Margin>
                    <OnIdiom Phone="10" Tablet="20" Desktop="20"/>
                </Image.Margin>
            </Image>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</Grid>
```

Is there a way to keep the size of the image in proportion to the actual size?

Comment: What OS are we talking about? Also, what do you believe, is the function of "AspectFit"?

Comment: Please read the docs on `Aspect`

Comment: Note that the issue here is that the Image is being given more vertical space than it needs. This feels like a `layout` problem, not an `Aspect` problem. I'm drawing a blank as to why VerticalStackLayout might give the image more height than needed. Suggestions for OP?  @copang, does it still happen if you remove `ScrollView`? (I realize you may want ScrollView, but this is a valuable test to determine the cause.)

Comment: You could try set the widthrequest or heightrequest for the image.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, I tried removing the ScrollView and even the StackLayout but the result is the same

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT, I'm trying to avoid set width & height, because I'm looking for a way to let the View calculate the size automatic. I used to use the solution here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a20da770-496c-4d25-981a-21e3398e2f68/image-in-stacklayout-full-width?forum=xamarinforms, but it doesn't work with .NET MAUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some changes:

1. I tried using data binding in MVVM way.
2. I tried counting image ratio using platform code.

The following is my code,

**For MainPage.xaml**, the difference is that i use data binding for image Source and AspectRatio property which would be claimed in MainPageVeiwModel.

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout>                          
            <a:AspectImage Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"
                     AspectRatio="{Binding AspectRatio}" Aspect="AspectFit" BackgroundColor="Blue">
                <a:AspectImage.Margin>
                    <OnIdiom Phone="10" Tablet="20" Desktop="20"/>
                </a:AspectImage.Margin>
            </a:AspectImage>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</Grid>
```

**For custom control AspectImage**, the difference is that I changed AspectRatio to Bindable property as we use binding for this property. More info [Bindable properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties?view=net-maui-7.0).

```
public class AspectImage : Image
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty AspectRatioProperty = BindableProperty.Create("AspectRatio", typeof(double), typeof(AspectRatioContainer), null);

    public double AspectRatio
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(AspectRatioProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AspectRatioProperty, value); }
    }

    public AspectImage()
    {
        SizeChanged += HandleSizeChanged;
    }

    private void HandleSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Width > 0 && AspectRatio > 0)
        {
            var desiredHeightRequest = this.Width * AspectRatio;
            if ((int)desiredHeightRequest != (int)HeightRequest)
            {
                this.HeightRequest = (int)desiredHeightRequest;
                InvalidateMeasure();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**For MainPageViewModel**, we add AspectRatio and ImageUrl property for custom control and count AspectRatio.

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public double AspectRatio { get; set; }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        ImageUrl = "https://cdn-5e5150f5f911c807c41ebdc8.closte.com/wp-content/uploads/IoT-development-kit-article-banner-scaled-900x400.jpg";

        AspectRatio = CountAspectRatio(ImageUrl);
    }

    private double CountAspectRatio(string imageUrl)
    {
        var service = new GetImageSizeService();
        Size imageSize = service.GetImageSize(imageUrl);
        return imageSize.Height / imageSize.Width;
    }
}
```

From above code in MainPageViewModel, we count AspectRatio by call platform code. If you are not familiar with it, i recommend this tutorial first: [How To Write Platform-Specific Code in .NET MAUI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsO6pXz0umc).

To inject platform code in Maui (in Xamarin could use DependencyService):

First, in Project folder, create a new partial class, let's call it GetImageSizeService:

```
public partial class GetImageSizeService
{
    public partial Size GetImageSize(string file);
}
```

Then creat another partial class in Platforms/iOS folder, called it GetImageSizeService also. **Pay attention to the namespace should be the same as above file**.

```
public partial class GetImageSizeService
{
    public partial Size GetImageSize(string file)
    {
        NSData data = NSData.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromString(file));

        UIImage image = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
        return new Size((double)image.Size.Width, (double)image.Size.Height);
    }
}
```

Then in MainPageViewModel, we just call this service and count the AspectRatio.

=========================== First post=============

The link you add did inspire me. And if i understand your question correctly, you could try the following code which worked for me:

Create AspectImage custom control which set aspect ratio for width and height

```
public class AspectImage : Image
{
    public double AspectRatio { get; set; }

    public AspectImage()
    {
        SizeChanged += HandleSizeChanged;
    }

    private void HandleSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Width > 0 && AspectRatio > 0)
        {
            var desiredHeightRequest = this.Width * AspectRatio;           
            if ((int)desiredHeightRequest != (int)HeightRequest)
            {
                this.HeightRequest = (int)desiredHeightRequest;
                InvalidateMeasure();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For xaml, consume the AspectImage. Here the aspect ratio seems to be 4/9 Approximately equal to 0.44

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout>                          
            <a:AspectImage Source="https://cdn-5e5150f5f911c807c41ebdc8.closte.com/wp-content/uploads/IoT-development-kit-article-banner-scaled-900x400.jpg"
                     AspectRatio="0.44" Aspect="AspectFit" BackgroundColor="Blue">
                <a:AspectImage.Margin>
                    <OnIdiom Phone="10" Tablet="20" Desktop="20"/>
                </a:AspectImage.Margin>
            </a:AspectImage>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</Grid>
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Can an image source be asked for its width and height? Would avoid need to manually set aspect ratio.

Comment: It works exactly as I expected, thank you very much. And like @ToolmakerSteve said, it would be great if it could detect the ratio by itself.

Comment: Yes, it could, but using platform code. I will update my answer soon.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks very much for your suggestion. I didn't consider this point  and now I try getting width and height by using platform code.

Comment: @copang I have updated my answer to get the image width and height and then count ratio. You could have a try.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT I just found a problem, when I use AspectImage as item inside CollectionView, it seems that CollectionView still doesn't update according to new size of AspectImage (as a result each item has very large height), only when I drag CollectionView everything just updated.

Comment: Sorry that i cannot reproduce it. I recommend that you could start a new thread and post relevant code and more people could help you.