# Get true size of resizing image in absoluteLayout in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I have an image in an absolute layout in my .NET MAUI porgram. I would like the image to resize automatically but I also want to know the layouts/windows size and the image size so I can place new images on top of the first one relative to the first image. (I basically want the image to be my coordinate system for new, smaller images). The thing is when I access the Images width and height (form the .xaml Object in my code-behind) I get the size of the window/layout instead. Like this I cant calculate the margin left and above the image and cant place the new images properly.

I tried to change AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags from "All" or "SizeProportional" to "None" but like so will not resize the image when the window is resized. I also tried adding an custom image handler but with little success.

Maybe switching to the .NET MAUI canvas would be better? Idk

Comment: Just so you know canvas is a [GraphicsView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.graphicsview?view=net-maui-7.0) in maui, you can draw element but there is no way to handle events on them (you will not be able to get click events on the images).

Comment: Btw somone downvoted probably because you didn't add a code sample of what you already tried, pretty rude of them if you ask me ...

Comment: @Poulpynator I mean I could have added the things I tried but I wanted to get rid of it because it was really a big mess. I wanted a clean new start. I will remember to add code in my future posts. Thank you for telling me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to handle positionning while handling responsive design you will have some pretty hard times (whatever the plateform you will be using).

The main problem you will encounter is handling aspect ratio since the relative position will change if the aspect change. Your best bet is to have it fixed (most likely the background image will not change), if you do that you can position the element relatively and it should work. Here is an exemple based on that :

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp1">
    <AbsoluteLayout
        Grid.Row="0"
        Background="Red"
        x:Name="AbsLayoutContainer">
        <AbsoluteLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
        </AbsoluteLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <Image
            x:Name="BackgroundImage"
            Source="dotnet_bot.png"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0, 1, 1"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="SizeProportional" />
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And in the code behind :

```
namespace MauiApp1
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private Size GetImageSize()
        {
            return new Size(100, 100);
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            SizeChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                Size imageSize = GetImageSize();
                var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
                double ratio = imageSize.Width / imageSize.Height;

                AbsLayoutContainer.WidthRequest = mainDisplayInfo.Width;
                AbsLayoutContainer.HeightRequest = mainDisplayInfo.Width / ratio;
            };
        }

        // You may want to change the AbsLayoutContainer size there based on the parent size
        protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
        {
            base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
        }

        private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
        {
            AbsLayoutContainer.ScaleTo(2);

            var position = e.GetPosition(AbsLayoutContainer).Value;
            Image newImage = new Image
            {
                Source = "dotnet_bot.png",
                HeightRequest = 50,
                WidthRequest = 50
            };

            TapGestureRecognizer lTapEvent = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            lTapEvent.Tapped += (_, __) => { 
                AbsLayoutContainer.Children.Remove(newImage);
                AbsLayoutContainer.ScaleTo(1);
            };
            newImage.GestureRecognizers.Add(lTapEvent);

            AbsLayoutContainer.Children.Add(newImage);
            AbsLayoutContainer.SetLayoutFlags(newImage,     Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
            AbsLayoutContainer.SetLayoutBounds(newImage, new Rect(new Point(position.X /    AbsLayoutContainer.Width, position.Y / AbsLayoutContainer.Height), new Size(50)));
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you want a way to get your image background size and resize your absolute layout based on that, I already made something similar (there is no standard way of getting an image file dimension in MAUI as far as I know).

As it turn out it's pretty difficult to get the dimension of an image from a resource, if that's not the case your case you can check how to get the dimensions [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75485581/10404482).

Comment: Thank you very much for spending you time helping me. This works and I am very happy right now. I was stuck on this problem for days now and I need it for work so really thank you very much.

Yes I would love a way to resize the absolute layout. In the final product you should be able to zoom and move the main image around all while the small images stay on their relative position on the main image (and you should be able to tap them later on but I should be able to manage that myself). If you would be willing to help me with that I would be very happy. Thanky ou so much.

Comment: @Timpl I edited my answer so that the AbsoluteLayout take the size of the background image, so that you know you can also handle zoom and position with [Transforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/transforms), Scale for zoom and Translate for position.

Comment: Thank you! I try to do the rest by myself. I thought transformations were only for the canvas. Good that that's not the case. Thank you again and have a very nice day :)