# .NET MAUI how to make the border same size as the image?

Tags: maui

Code:

```
<Grid>
   <Border  BackgroundColor="Aqua">
        <Image 
            x:Name="cardImage"
            Source="test4.png"
            Aspect="AspectFit"
            />
   </Border>
</Grid>
```

I am expecting this code to generate a border as big as the image, however I get below instead. I am not clear what is the reason for the spaces above and below the image.

How can I make the size of the border as high as the image ?

EDIT: Adding a full XAML. Image is any PNG that is 640x640px.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="Test101.MainPage">
    
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Grid>
                <Border BackgroundColor="Aqua">
                    <Image Source="atom_1.png" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

[image]

Comment: The image is being AspectFit into space available from Grid. Border has no way of knowing image is not using the full space it was given. Add to question the declarations of surrounding layouts, starting from root of xaml (contentpage?)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, thank you. This is exactly it. But then the question is why the Border gets an arbitrary height ? If I remove the Image, Border resizes to 0 x 0, so that's why I was expecting it to be as big as the image, after adding an image in.

Comment: @Charles full XAML please.

Comment: @Charles. That is what I tried to explain. The image has sized itself to the grid cell. Then it drew itself, but did not use the full height. I know it looks a certain size, but internally, the height of the area it owns became as tall as the grid.

Comment: Wrap border with verticalstacklayout having vertical layout = Center. Better advice is possible if you show more xaml surrounding what you show. Please read carefully what I asked in first comment.

Comment: Thanks for the comments a full XAML added now. Any PNG of size 640x640 should be able to produce the same result.

Comment: @Charles I remember a guy asking for something very similar, quite some time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75470529/net-maui-image-wrong-size. The answer is very interesting. In more than one ways.

Comment: I've got a solution, if fixes the problem but a bit hap hazard. Basically I bind Border's HeightRequest to Image's Width. And it surrounds the image perfectly. But it came from a trial and error and I cannot explain why it works. Will post it as an answer if no one offers a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
     <Border                   
        Stroke="#C49B33"
        StrokeThickness="6"
        StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 0,0,0,0"
        Background="#2B0B98"
        Padding="0"
         >
        <Image  BackgroundColor="Pink" 
        Source="test.jpg"
        Aspect="AspectFit"
        />
    </Border>
```

Comment: Thank you, which part of this code expected to make the Border as big as the Image ?

Comment: The size of the `Border` is automatically adjusted according to the size of the image.